# Multiple warnings when trying to profile my app? Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I am trying to profile my app in instruments and every time I hit profile I get well over 300 dependency warnings, but it works just fine to build it in debug mode. I am using kobold2d.
These are some of the warnings:

```
cocos2d-extensions-ios Group
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/CCBigImage/CCBigImage.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/CCBigImage/CCTextureCache+CCBigImageExtensions.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/CCMenuAdvanced/CCMenuAdvanced.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/CCMenuItemSpriteIndependent/CCMenuItemSpriteIndependent.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/CCScrollLayer/CCScrollLayer.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/CCSendMessages/CCSendMessages.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/CCSlider/CCSlider.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/CCVideoPlayer/Mac/CCVideoPlayerImplMac.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/CCVideoPlayer/Mac/MyMovieView.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/FilesDownloader/FilesDownloader.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/FilesDownloader/SingleFileDownloader.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/CCLayerPanZoom/CCLayerPanZoom.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/TMXGenerator/cencode.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/TMXGenerator/LFCGzipUtility.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/Extensions/TMXGenerator/TMXGenerator.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
chipmunk-spacemanager-ios Group
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk-SpaceManager/src/ccExtras/cpCCNode.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk-SpaceManager/src/ccExtras/cpCCNodeImpl.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk-SpaceManager/src/ccExtras/cpCCSprite.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk-SpaceManager/src/ccExtras/cpConstraintNode.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk-SpaceManager/src/ccExtras/cpShapeNode.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk-SpaceManager/src/ccExtras/SpaceManagerCocos2d.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk-SpaceManager/src/cpExtras/cpPulleyJoint.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk-SpaceManager/src/cpSpaceSerializer/cpSpaceSerializer.cpp' of type sourcecode.cpp.cpp for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk-SpaceManager/src/cpSpaceSerializer/tinyxml/tinystr.cpp' of type sourcecode.cpp.cpp for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk-SpaceManager/src/cpSpaceSerializer/tinyxml/tinyxml.cpp' of type sourcecode.cpp.cpp for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk-SpaceManager/src/cpSpaceSerializer/tinyxml/tinyxmlerror.cpp' of type sourcecode.cpp.cpp for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk-SpaceManager/src/cpSpaceSerializer/tinyxml/tinyxmlparser.cpp' of type sourcecode.cpp.cpp for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk-SpaceManager/src/SpaceManager.mm' of type sourcecode.cpp.objcpp for architecture armv6
chipmunk-ios Group
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/chipmunk.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/constraints/cpConstraint.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/constraints/cpDampedRotarySpring.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/constraints/cpDampedSpring.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/constraints/cpGearJoint.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/constraints/cpGrooveJoint.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/constraints/cpPinJoint.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/constraints/cpPivotJoint.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/constraints/cpRatchetJoint.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/constraints/cpRotaryLimitJoint.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/constraints/cpSimpleMotor.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/constraints/cpSlideJoint.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpArbiter.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpArray.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpBB.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpBBTree.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpBody.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpCollision.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpHashSet.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpPolyShape.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpShape.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpSpace.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpSpaceComponent.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpSpaceHash.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpSpaceQuery.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpSpaceStep.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpSpatialIndex.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpSweep1D.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/Chipmunk/src/cpVect.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
objectal-ios Group
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Actions/OALAction.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Actions/OALActionManager.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Actions/OALAudioActions.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Actions/OALFunction.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Actions/OALUtilityActions.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/AudioTrack/OALAudioTrack.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/AudioTrack/OALAudioTrackNotifications.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/AudioTrack/OALAudioTracks.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OALSimpleAudio.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OpenAL/ALBuffer.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OpenAL/ALCaptureDevice.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OpenAL/ALChannelSource.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OpenAL/ALContext.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OpenAL/ALDevice.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OpenAL/ALListener.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OpenAL/ALSoundSourcePool.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OpenAL/ALSource.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OpenAL/ALWrapper.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OpenAL/OpenALManager.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Session/OALAudioSession.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Session/OALSuspendHandler.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Support/IOSVersion.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Support/mach_timing.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Support/OALAudioFile.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Support/OALTools.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
cocosdenshion-ios Group
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone/CocosDenshion/CocosDenshion/CDAudioManager.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone/CocosDenshion/CocosDenshion/CDOpenALSupport.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone/CocosDenshion/CocosDenshion/CocosDenshion.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone/CocosDenshion/CocosDenshion/SimpleAudioEngine.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone/CocosDenshion/CocosDenshionExtras/CDXPropertyModifierAction.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/cocos2d-iphone/CocosDenshion/CocosDenshionExtras/CDXMacOSXSupport.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
sneakyinput-ios Group
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/SneakyInput/Classes/ColoredCircleSprite.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/SneakyInput/Classes/ColoredSquareSprite.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/SneakyInput/Classes/SneakyButton.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/SneakyInput/Classes/SneakyButtonSkinnedBase.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/SneakyInput/Classes/SneakyJoystick.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/SneakyInput/Classes/SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/SneakyInput/Classes/SneakyJoystickSkinnedDPadExample.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libs/SneakyInput/Classes/SneakyJoystickSkinnedJoystickExample.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
```